# Flash builder cannot locate required debugger version

Tags: flash-builder

My old workspace was starting to throw some errors when closing, so I created a new workspace and imported the project into the new workspace. Unfortunately I cannot debug the new workspace. I keep getting the error:

Flash Builder cannot locate the required debugger version of Adobe Flash Player.

I have uninstalled the debugger and re-installed, but still no luck. All other workspaces, including the old one, have no problem debugging. Any idea what could be causing this? Everything I've seen just says to uninstall and reinstall the debugger, which I've already done.

Thanks

Pete

Comment: I think the folder that you're doing the debugging in matters. Did you move the debug location from the default folder?

Comment: Yes, I moved the debug location

Comment: Yeah, I've never gotten it to work when I moved the debug location. So if you want a quick fix, move it back